# Count by Year Based on Criterion in R

Tags: r, count

I am trying to count the number of rows with values fcoli>15 and produce a vector sorting these counts by year.

Some sample data:

```
Year <- c(1996,1996,1997,19971998,1999,1999,1999)
fcoli <- c(45,13,96,10,52,53,64,5)
sample <- data.frame(Year,fcoli)
```

I have been able to count the number of rows one year at a time using:

```
nrow(subset(sample, sample$fcoli > 15 & sample$Year == 1996))
```

However I have not been able to use this criterion to produce counts for all the years at once. My actual data consists of over 20 years of data and so I would rather not have to manually iterate this code for each year.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You want to count the number of `fcoli > 15` per each year? Does this help `aggregate(fcoli ~ Year, sample, function(x) sum(x > 15))`?

Comment: You can do `sapply(split(sample$fcoli,sample$Year),function(z) sum(z>15))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple enough answer.

```
Year <- c(1996,1996,1997,1997,1998,1999,1999,1999)
fcoli <- c(45,13,96,10,52,53,64,5)
sample <- data.frame(Year,fcoli)
aggregate(fcoli~Year,FUN=length,data=sample[sample$fcoli>15,])
```

Comment: Or alternatively `aggregate( fcoli>15 ~ Year, sample, sum )` (since you can sum logical values to find the number of TRUE values)

Comment: Thank you! The aggregate function is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 library(dplyr) 
 df1%>%   #df1 is yor data frame
 filter(fcoli>15) %>%
 group_by(Year)%>%
 summarise(freq=n())

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  Year freq
1 1996    1
2 1997    1
3 1998    1
4 1999    2
```

Comment: After `filter(fcoli > 15)`, `count(Year)` could be another option.

Comment: I agree . It could be another option. Thanks.

Comment: Or  `sample %>% filter(fcoli > 15) %>% group_by(Year) %>% tally()`